# How can I configure anaconda kickstart to assure its installs all updates from start?

Tags: fedora, kickstart, anaconda

I am using anaconda kickstart installer to provision fedora 28 baremetals but I found that by default i does not install all updates.

I do want to avoid having to run a an `yum -q -y update` during the `%post` phase an find a way in which the initial installation would be using the latest updates, saving a lot of time by avoiding to download and install things twice.

How can I do this?

If the solution would work for the entire RedHat family: Fedora/CentOS/RHEL the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install all updates at installation time, you need to have the `updates` repo defined in the kickstart using [the `repo` option](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax#idm140322346790848).

For example:

```
url --mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-29&arch=x86_64
repo --name=updates --mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f29&arch=x86_64
```

This will install Fedora 29 from the network, and also install any available updates, from the Internet using the nearest available mirror.

You can change 29 to 28 each place it appears, to install the older Fedora 28 instead. But be aware of its short lifecycle.

If you have a private mirror, you can use that instead of using a mirrorlist.

```
repo --name=updates --baseurl=http://myprivaterepo.example/fedora/linux/updates/29/Everything/x86_64
```

Comment: What I do not underatand is why I need to mention the baseurl because once installed yum/dnf can find updates with no problems.

Comment: @sorin Because at the point you are installing the system from a kickstart, the system is not yet installed. You have to tell anaconda where to get the files from somehow!